# My Mazda 626 is loosing power steering; however, it is NOT leaking under car... What's wrong?

Tags: mazda, power-steering, power

My Mazda 626 is loosing power steering; however, it is NOT leaking under car. What's wrong?

I am not a mechanic; I'm puzzled why I'm loosing power steering fluid; however, it is not visibly leaking!  I put power steering fluid in today; yet, it was hard to turn a few hours later.

Comment: This problem is an on-going problem...  It began months ago...  I added power steering fluid once a month, then once a week, now it looks like daily...  I only drive the car less than 500 miles per month...

Comment: Note that you can edit to add to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you give a little detail about [your](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_626) car generation or made year, since there might be variation on power steering system.

Does the car manual or auto transmission? Is it share power steering fluid with clutch fluid, leak might occurred at clutch cylinder where you might did'n look at.

**Edit:** read the problem description again and found that you have fluid lost but don't found any leak, sorry. Keep the previous answer just in cast that might help others

---

Assume your system is pure hydraulic-based. Power loss in hydraulic system might occurred without any leak due to worn/leak internal system. Or it can be from not enough power to drive the pump.

1. Have you check the power pump belt?
2. Have you look for any unusual thing that might block the steering rod or wheel from moving?
3. Are there any unusual resistance to the engine (belt make noise) when you try to turn?
4. The power steering is not assisted at all (like your didn't run the engine) or it lost some power?

PS. sorry for my bad English

Comment: My car is a 1997 Mazda 626, automatic transmission...  The belt does make noise when I turn it and the fluid is low...

Comment: My car is a 1997 Mazda 626, automatic transmission...  The belt does make noise when I turn it and the fluid is low...  I have not checked the power pump belt or if there is some blockage...  It acts like there is no power sterring...

Comment: When I start the car, the steering feels like a car without power steering...very difficult to turn...  Thanks for directing me to possibilities to check...